# How to get all the indexes and filter the indexes by using Nest in C#

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I need to list all the indexes and types in Elasticsearch.

Basically I use `_client.stats().Indices` to acquire the indexes, and filter using `foreach` excluded index list like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, Stats> AllIndexes()
{
    _client = new ElasticClient(setting);
    var result = _client.Stats();
    var allIndex = result.Indices;
    var excludedIndexList = ExcludedIndexList();
    foreach (var index in excludedIndexList)
    {
        if (allIndex.ContainsKey(index)) allIndex.Remove(index);
    }

    return allIndex;
}
```

Is this right way to do to list all the indexes from Elasticsearch or is there a better way?

Answer (score 12):

`GetIndexAsync` is removed from `Assembly Nest, Version=7.0.0.0` 
from `Version=7.0.0.0` you can use this :

```
 var result = await _client.Indices.GetAsync(new GetIndexRequest(Indices.All));
```

Answer (score 3):

This works, a slightly sexier way of writing it would be using `.Except()` on result.Indices.

Another route would be by using `.CatIndices()`

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html

Comment: But there isn't away to specify a wildcard filter via NEST 1.9.

Answer (score 2):

Code `Assembly Nest, Version=6.0.0.0` as below

```
var result = await _client.GetIndexAsync(null, c => c
                                     .AllIndices()
                             );
```

you will get result in `result.Indices.Keys` string list

Answer (score 0):

In Version=7.0.0.0 the method GetIndexAsync doesn't accept null any more.
The solution:

```
var response = await _searchClient.Cat.IndicesAsync(c => c.AllIndices());
var logIndexes = response.Records.Select(a => a.Index).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is still looking...With NEST 7.* I ended up with:

```
public async Task<IReadonlyList<string>> GetIndicesByPattern(string indexNamePrefix)
{
    CatResponse<CatIndicesRecord>? result = await esClient.Cat.IndicesAsync(i => i.index(indexNamePrefix));
    return result.Records.Select(i => i.Index).ToList();
}
```